# Remote Desktop connection error Remote Desktop Services is currently busy

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2016

I'm using remote desktop from windows 10 to connect to my remote server that running windows server 2016 but many times error occurs returning me the following message

The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote Desktop Services is currently busy. Please try again in a few minutes. Other users should still be able to log on.

Comment: Check the %cpu, if a task hit 100% it will cause trouble like that

Comment: It's not related to cpu usage. after this error i cant log in again by that user but other users still ok till this error happened to them

Comment: Have you installed latest patches on this server? As every young MS Server, it needs it.

Comment: Yes I install all patches

Comment: This problem goes back to 2008 and it had a hotfix around then, but not for newer OS versions, even though it's still affecting people through Server 2016.